# VSTS npm custom build task - run npm script fails with type error

Tags: npm, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, npm-run

I've defined some scripts in my package.json, e.g.,

```
    "config": {
    "source": "./assets/stylesheets/civica-styles.scss",
    "dist": "./dist/civica-styles.css",
    "minCss": "./dist/civica-styles.min.css"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "transpile": "cross-var node-sass $npm_package_config_source $npm_package_config_dist",
    "minify": "cross-var cleancss -o $npm_package_config_minCss $npm_package_config_dist"
  }
```

I can run these at the command line as follows

```
npm run transpile
```

I have set up a build in VSTS that performs the following initial tasks:

1. Get Sources (get my code from the repo)
2. npm install (installs the
       packages defined in my package.json)

Now I want to add a task that runs my `transpile` defined in `package.json`, so I added the following `npm custom` task

- Display name => npm transpile
- Command => custom
- Command and arguments => run transpile

However the build fails with

```
2017-08-01T10:01:42.5125804Z ##[section]Starting: npm custom
2017-08-01T10:01:42.5125804Z ==============================================================================
2017-08-01T10:01:42.5125804Z Task         : npm
2017-08-01T10:01:42.5125804Z Description  : Install and publish npm packages, or run an npm command. Supports npmjs.com and authenticated registries like Package Management.
2017-08-01T10:01:42.5125804Z Version      : 1.0.3
2017-08-01T10:01:42.5125804Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2017-08-01T10:01:42.5125804Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613746)
2017-08-01T10:01:42.5125804Z ==============================================================================
2017-08-01T10:01:43.3515881Z ##[error]TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of null
2017-08-01T10:01:43.3565858Z ##[section]Finishing: npm custom
```

Any ideas of how to execute an npm run script from a VSTS build task?

Comment: Did you use hosted agent or your own private agent? What's the installed node.js version if you use private agent?

Answer (score 0):

Check **Working folder with package.json** box of npm task. It is the **folder** path **not the file**, you can use `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`.

Answer (score 0):

Running npm from the PowerShell task worked for me.

1. Set type to "Inline"
2. Write your task in the "Script" box eg. `npm run test`
3. Make sure "Working Directory" is set to the package.json folder under "Advanced"

[image: example]